# Is it possible to load Bootstrap Glyphicon icons remotely with jQuery/AJAX in Rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using Rails 4, jQuery and AJAX. Currently I can toggle between "incomplete" and "complete" links on 'ideas'. Here is my js.erb file:

```
$("#toggle_link_" + <%= @idea.id %>).text("<%= @idea.completed? ? 'Incomplete' : 'Complete' %>")
```

Is it possible to load Bootstrap Glyphicon icons with jQuery? For example instead having a link called "complete", I would have a glyphicon icon:

```
'<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>'.html_safe
```

Comment: you dont need to load glyphicon with ajax you just need to add class to the elemets. Icons are already loaded in page.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @jbmyid. Do you know how can I add a class to a one line ruby 'if else' statement?